# Keycloak: users have been disabled/blocked with no clear explanation

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

After some occurrences, I've noticed that some users in Keycloak (version 19.0.1) have been disabled without a clear reason.

There is one situation that, after only 2 minutes after manually enable the user, it was disabled again by some sort of trigger. Sometimes it does not happen this fast, but same behavior could be noticed after some days.

What could disable or block users from Keycloak other than the limit of access attempts? Is there any kind of setup that rules that?

Comment: Keycloak brute force protection?

Comment: I don't think it could be this, because there were no attempts according to the own user. So, if the user is disabled or blocked without having attempts to login, I'm in doubt what could be the other reasons

Comment: Any attacker can try to guess user password. Anyway, did you check the logs - that should be esential part of the investigation.