# Keycloak randomly disable user accounts?

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

Recently there have been occurrences where users suddenly receive the message "account is disabled, contact your administrator" when trying to log in. For one user, clearing his cache and restarting his PC solved the issue, for another, he just waited for a while. The version of keycloak being used it 17.0.0.

Does anybody know what causes this situation to incorrectly occur? And if so, any advice on how to resolve this? Thank you !!

Comment: Duplicated question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73198494/keycloak-users-have-been-disabled-blocked-with-no-clear-explanation

Comment: Have you enabled brute force protection?

Comment: Brute force protection is turned off